# In C++, how would I make a random number (either 1 or 2) that changes every 5 minutes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, timer

I'm trying to make a simple game and I have a shop in the game. I want it to be every 5 minutes(if the function changeItem() is called) the item in the shop either switches or stays the same. I have no problem generating the random number, but I have yet to find a thread that shows how to make it generate differently each 5 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: This should not be tied to the system clock, but to "game time", i.e. how much time has elapsed *inside the game environment*.  All you need to do is check (probably in the function that determines the contents of the shop) how much game time has elapsed since the last time the contents of the shop were examined, and reroll them if it's been long enough.

Comment: Try call srand(time(NULL)); before call rand().

Comment: Agree with @Zack; bringing timers or threading into the architecture just to do this is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

In short, keep track of the last time the `changeItem()` function was called. If it is more than 5 minutes since the last time it was called, then use your random number generator to generate a new number. Otherwise, use the saved number from the last time it was generated.

Answer (score 1):

You've already accepted an answer but I would like to say that for apps that need simple timing like this and don't need great accuracy, a simple calculation in the main loop as all you need.

Kicking off a thread for a single timer is a lot of unnecessary overhead.
So, here's the code showing how you'd go about doing it.

```
#define FIVE_MINUTES (60*5)

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  time_t lastChange = 0, tick; 
  run_game_loop = true;

  while (run_game_loop){
     // ... game loop

     tick = time(NULL);
     if ((tick - lastChange) >= FIVE_MINUTES){
         changeItem();
         lastChange = tick;
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It somewhat assumes to be called reasonably regularly though.  If on the other hand you need it accurate then a thread would be better.  And depending on platform there exist API's for timers that get called by the system.

Comment: I agree about timers.  Unfortunately theses are not portable.  On the other side, if the goal is to make a game, using threads is a valid architecture.  Last but not least, your loop keeps the processor busy just for counting time.  The threaded approach with sleeps() frees CPU when it's not needed increasing performance of other tasks and lowering battery consumption for portable devices.

Comment: @Christophe - you might think that the threaded approach makes the CPU busier but actually in comparison to the rest of the game logic, time(NULL) and a few checks is so tiny as to not be a performance bottleneck as you assume.  My approach can also be extended for other timing tasks.  With your loop you'd have to create another thread unless you made the thread universal.  You also forgot about context switching for your thread.  That might negate my test and may even be heavier than a time(NULL).  I don't think either way is going to flatten your laptop battery any more or less.

Comment: @Christophe - I would use your approach if I absolutely needed a very accurate time. We can use frameworks that provide cross platform timers if needed.

Comment: +1 for the frameworks. About context switching, a thread is lighweight (it's not a full task with its own environment): the switch is only about storing the registers on a monocore processor, so not much more that a function call.  Anyway nowadays most CPUS are multicore (i.e. multithread in hardware).  My point with CPU consumption was not within the game, but in general as the PC/or the smartphone might perform concurrent tasks not related to the game).  But your solution fits well in a traditional game loop architecture :-)

Answer (score -1):

***Standard and portable approach:***

You could consider C++11 threads.  The general idea would be :

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void myrandogen ()   // function that refreshes your randum number:
                     // will be executed as a thread  
{
     while (! gameover ) {
        this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::minutes(5));   // wait 5 minutes  
        ... // generate your random number and update your game data structure
        }
}
```

in the main function, you would then instantiate a thread with your function:

```
thread t1 (myrandomgen);  // create an launch thread 

... // do your stuff until game over

t1.join ();    // wait until thread returns
```

Of course you could also pass parameters (references to shared variables, etc...) when you create the thread, like this:

```
 thread t1 (myrandomgen,  param1, param2, ....);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's standard and portable.

***Non-portable alternatives:***

I'm less familiar with these, but:

- In a MSWIN environment, you could use SetTimer(...) to define a function to be called at regular interval (and KillTimer(...) to delete it).  But this requires a programm structure build around the windows event processing loop.
- In a linux environment, you could similarly define a call back function with signal(SIGALRM, ...) and activate periodic calls with alarm().

***Small update on performance considerations:*** 
Following several reamrks about overkill of therads and performance, I've done a benchmark, executing 1 billion loop iterations an waiting 1 microsecond each 100K iterations.  The whole thing was run on an i7 multicore CPU:

- Non threaded execution yielded 213K iterations per millisec.
- 2 thread execution yielded 209K iterations per millisec and per thread. So slightly slower for each thread.  The total execution time was however only 70 to 90 ms longer, so that the overall throughput is at 418 K iterations.

How come ?  Because the second thread is using a non used core on the processor.  This means that with the adequate architecture, a game could process many more calculatios when using multithreading...

Comment: Could the one who downvoted this working solution please explain the reason and give me opportunity to improve ?

Comment: Abusing a thread for a single timer is overkill. Especially in a game context, where there's almost always a fixed-rate main loop anyway, running at a frequency much higher than the 5 minutes needed here.

Comment: @Matt I wasn't suspecting you:  you made a valuable answer, so I assumed that you'd find my answer relevant, even if we do not fully agree on what's the ultiamte approach ;-)

Comment: @MSalters you are right for the 5 minutes.  But there are two parts in my response:  the most standard one (the threads which you criticize) and the most performant non standard ones (timers in win and alarm in linux):  do you consider both as bad response ??

Comment: @Christophe: Well, the Windows part is incomplete. `SetWaitableTimer` doesn't require event processing. And on Linux, there's very little you can do in a signal handler (large parts of the Standard Library aren't async-safe). Besides, `alarm` allows only one timer (you'd want `timer_create`)